# Internet Explorer Compatability View settings

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

Windows 7, IE 11 does not keep the compatibilty websites listings, have to enter them every time I go to certain websites

Comment: "Windows Explorer" is a file explorer, do you mean "Internet Explorer"? And if so, which version of Internet Explorer are you using?  Are you saying that sites you add to the list in Compatibility View Settings vanish?  If so, when do they vanish (when you close IE, or reboot, or ???)?  Is this your personal computer, or is it company-supplied?

Comment: Yes, they vanish, company computer, when I close IE or add new tab

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say it's a company computer, then it's most likely getting cleared by [Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx).

You'll have to discuss it with your company's SysAdmin, as they will have to adjust the [related polices](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2013/10/23/how-to-add-web-site-to-compatibility-view-list-via-gpo.aspx) to accommodate you.